# IOS toolbar Icons color is changing when Gradient toolbar applied

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm developing an IOS Application using Xamarin.Forms and in that I've customized the toolbar color to Gradient color using custom renderers.But,After this the Icons
color is changed as per the toolbar color and how to set the title text to white colour.Here is the renderer I'm using for toolbar customization

```
public class NavigationPageGradientHeaderRenderer:NavigationRenderer
{
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        var control = (NavigationPageGradientHeader)this.Element;

        var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();
        gradientLayer.Bounds = NavigationBar.Bounds;
        gradientLayer.Colors = new CGColor[] { control.RightColor.ToCGColor(), control.LeftColor.ToCGColor() };
        gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0.0, 0.5);
        gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(1.0, 0.5);

        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(gradientLayer.Bounds.Size);
        gradientLayer.RenderInContext(UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext());
        UIImage image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

        NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(image, UIBarMetrics.Default);
    }
}
```

After applying this the Icons look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOoIZ.png)

But I want the images background to be transparent like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99fGX.jpg)
and the title textcolor should be white.

How can I achieve this.Can anyone please help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try setting the `BarTextColor` property of `NavigationPage`?

Comment: @G.hakim Yeah,I've tried setting that property but it doesn't effect the text color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the property in `CustomRenderer`

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        var control = (MyNativePage)Element;

        var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();
        gradientLayer.Bounds = NavigationBar.Bounds;
        gradientLayer.Colors = new CGColor[] { UIColor.Red.CGColor,UIColor.White.CGColor };
        gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0.0, 0.5);
        gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(1.0, 0.5);

        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(gradientLayer.Bounds.Size);
        gradientLayer.RenderInContext(UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext());
        UIImage image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

        NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(image, UIBarMetrics.Default);


        NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.White;
        NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes() { ForegroundColor =UIColor.White};

    }
```

Comment: ,Thank you for the helpBut still I'm facing an issue.The issue is,If the Image background color is transparent it's working fine but if the image background color is somehing else ( For ex,White icon with blue background) then the icon is completely showing white color.Can you please help me with this

Comment: This is the issue of the image.I am afraid that you can not solve it by code.

Comment: @Mounika You can mark it as answer.Then create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an NavigationPage, then you can use like this

```
  var myHomePage = new NavigationPage(dashboardPage){

  Tint = Color.Red // put your color here };
```

You can set common color from App.xaml.cs;

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // MainPage = new MainPage(); 
        MainPage = new RESTAPICallApp.Controllers.HomePage();
        NavigationPage navigationRootPage = new NavigationPage(new RESTAPICallApp.Controllers.HomePage());
        navigationRootPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.LightSeaGreen;
        navigationRootPage.BarTextColor = Color.Wheat;
        MainPage = navigationRootPage;            
    }
```

For native Xamarin.iOS add this code in 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' method on AppDelegate.cs;

```
 UINavigationBar.Appearance.Translucent = false;
 UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.White
 UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes() {
        TextColor = UIColor.White,
        TextShadowColor = UIColor.Clear
    });
```

Comment: ,Thank you so much for the help. The solution you have suggested works for the Textcolor Property but how can I change the Icons color??

Thank you

Comment: Rightnow your icon color is white?

Comment: yeah @Prasanth,My Icon color is white.Please help me with this .I'll mark it as answer

Comment: I update my answer please check UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.White

Comment: Applying those properties doesn't effect anything

Comment: Did you add this line in Appdelegate UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false

Comment: yeah @Prasanth,I have added that line.I've tried with and without that line but no changes

Comment: It should work based on my experience in iOS native development, but here its not working, delete the build and try to run once again on device